# Multiple Column Comparison using IF in MySQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement

Please help with following `if` statement in MySQL 5.5. I am trying to compare column values to see if they are all equal or different.

```
SELECT IF(Column1 = Column2 = Column3 = Column4 = Column5, 'SAME', 'Different') 
AS ValueStatus 
FROM dbs.tabletest
GROUP BY Id
```

I have also tried the following, however, it only brings one type result as "Different" even when all columns have the same values.

```
  SELECT *,CASE 
  WHEN Column1 = Column2 = Column3 = Column4 = Column5 
    Then 'Same'
  ELSE 'Different' 
 END
  AS ValueStatus 
  FROM dbs.tabletest
  GROUP BY Id;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be `column1 = column2 and column1 = column3 and column1 = column4 and column1 = column5` instead.

What happened to you is probably you compared `column1` to `column2`, which returned `true`, then you compared `true` to `column3`, which yields `false`, compare `false` to `column4`, which also evaluates to `false`, etc.

Comment: Could you please further help on how to handle/ignore/filter out NULL values from these columns and only compare when NOT NULL, some columns have NULL values that change the status to different although all NOT NULL are Same values. Thanks

Comment: Adding Col 1 or COL 2 or COL 3 'Is NOT NULL' in Where clause doesn't bring correct results. Where all Null values carrying columns are ignored, Have to track NULLS but want these to be ignored while comparing equality of only NON NULL COLUMNS

Comment: Don't add it to your where clause. Either modify your IF statement or move to a CASE statement which may be a little bit easier to follow.

Comment: just replace comparisons with something like `IFNULL(column1=column2,TRUE) AND IFNULL(column1=column3,TRUE)...`

Comment: No luck so far with the following:
 Select *, IF(IFNULL( Col1 = Col2, TRUE)
 AND IFNULL(Col1 = Col3, TRUE)
 AND IFNULL( Col1= Col4, TRUE)
 AND IFNULL(Col1 = Col5,TRUE),
 'Same', 'Different' ) AS ValueStatus
    From db.tablename
     Group by Id ; Tried COALESCE instead of IFNULL , no luck, first row has col 1, 2, 3 similar but col4 and 5 null bring valuestatus as Different, Second row has col1, null and all other similar value, brings valuestatus as Different again; Thinking of switching to CASE SELECT, ...will wait for response, though

Comment: Following is what am trying to use and expecting to handle NULL in each column, Some Columns may have three NULL values as a row and may have column4 equal to column 5 that should bring the result as 'Same' Following are the details:

Comment: CASE statement, SELECT *, CASE

        WHEN COALESCE(column1 = column2 
       AND column1 = column3 
        AND column1 = column4 
        AND column1 = column5
       AND column2 = column3
        AND column2 = column4
       AND column2 = column5
       AND column3 = column4 
         AND column3 = column5
         AND column4 = column5)
       
        THEN 'Same'
        
        ELSE  'Different'                                   
    END AS ValueStatus 
     FROM dbs.tablename
          Group by Id ; Thanks for all help.

Comment: I had no idea `mysql` has `coalesce` :) Anyway, I think actually it's worse than that, because, if you ifnull/coalesce comparisons with col1 you have problem in case it's null. If you go for comparison with the next column, you'd have a problem with null-gaps. I'm not sure about mysql, in postgres I'd go for subquery that calculates the number of *distinct* values.

Comment: Maybe there's an equivalent for postgres construct `(select count(distinct x) from (values (c1),(c2),(c3),(c4),(c5)) as q(x))`...

Answer (score 0):

Michael's approch is right. i would use as following in MSSQL. not sure syntex in MySql. 
select 
    Case WHEN 
        ((column1 = column2) AND 
         (column1 = column3) and 
         (column1 = column4) and 
         (column1 = column5)
        ) 
        then 'Same' 
        ELSE 'Different' 
    end as 'ValueStatus'
FROM tableName

Comment: Yes, I also prefer `case` (mysql has it as well), but the part of interest was condition.